# Combine multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying different JOIN queries, but I'm not getting result I'm looking for.

I've got 2 tables:

```
Table 1: **StockItemShort**    

ItemID  | Code          | Name    
 432724 | CK002-16-09   | Green Daisy Pearl Earrings
 432759 | CK002-16-149  | Emerald Crystal Centre Daisy Earrings  

Table 2: **StockItemCatSearchValueShort**

ItemID |    SearchValueID
432724 |    388839
432724 |    389061
432724 |    390269
432724 |    389214
432759 |    388839
432759 |    389051
432759 |    390269
432759 |    389214
```

I can't get result I'm looking for.

I'd like to get following result:

```
ItemID  | Code  | Name  | SearchValueID | SearchValueID | SearchValueID | SearchValueID 
432724  | CK002-16-09   | Green Daisy Pearl Earrings    | 388839    | 389061    | 390269    | 389214
432759  | CK002-16-149  | Emerald Crystal Centre Daisy Earrings | 388839    | 389051    | 390269    | 389214
```

Comment: Once your number of Columns depends of the vertical size of your one-to-many table, Im afraid I dont have a Static Query that outputs its result, but you could programaticaly create a query like @Roman to output this result

Comment: I'll try Roman's pivot solution. Changing data into string is not the best solution.

Comment: Also just to clarify.. Number of column is static. In table StockItemCatSearchValueShort, 1 ItemID has always 4 SearchValueID's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have dynamic number of column like that, but you can **concatenate your data** into string:

```
select
    s.ItemID, s.Code, s.Name,
    stuff(
        (
            select ', ' + CAST(sv.SearchValueID AS VARCHAR)
            from ItemSearch as sv
            where sv.ItemID = s.ItemID
            for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(128)')
    , 1, 2, '') as SearchValues
from Item as s;
```

or you can **pivot rows** with [`PIVOT command`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or manually (*I prefer latter approach, it just seems more flexible for me, but `pivot` can greatly reduce amount of code in certain situations*):

```
with cte as (
    select
        *,
        row_number() over(partition by sv.ItemID order by sv.SearchValueID) as row_num
    from ItemSearch as sv
)
select
    s.ItemID, s.Code, s.Name,
    max(case when sv.row_num = 1 then sv.SearchValueID end) as SearchValueID1,
    max(case when sv.row_num = 2 then sv.SearchValueID end) as SearchValueID2,
    max(case when sv.row_num = 3 then sv.SearchValueID end) as SearchValueID3,
    max(case when sv.row_num = 4 then sv.SearchValueID end) as SearchValueID4
from Item as s
    inner join cte as sv on sv.ItemID = s.ItemID
group by s.ItemID, s.Code, s.Name
```

You also can turn previous statement into **dynamic SQL** like this:

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

select
    @stmt = 
        isnull(@stmt + ',','') + 
        'max(case when sv.row_num = ' + cast(rn as nvarchar(max)) +
        ' then sv.SearchValueID end) as SearchValueID' + cast(rn as nvarchar(max))
from (
    select distinct row_number() over(partition by ItemID order by SearchValueID) as rn
    from ItemSearch
) as a

select @stmt = '
    with cte as (
        select
            *,
            row_number() over(partition by sv.ItemID order by sv.SearchValueID) as row_num
        from ItemSearch as sv
    )
    select
        s.ItemID, s.Code, s.Name,' + @stmt + '
    from Item as s
        inner join cte as sv on sv.ItemID = s.ItemID
    group by s.ItemID, s.Code, s.Name;'

exec dbo.sp_executesql @stmt = @stmt
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dee00/41)</kbd>**

Comment: Number of column is static.

Comment: In table StockItemCatSearchValueShort, 1 ItemID has always 4 SearchValueID's.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Roman. When I paste code for pivot solution to SQLFiddle, I get following error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.