# Combine multiple rows into one row,different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have t table as below:

**Shop table:**

```
ShopID | PersonID
-----------------
  1    |  10001
  2    |  10002
  2    |  10003
```

**Person table**

```
PersonID | PersonName
---------------------
  10001  | Alex
  10002  | John
  10003  | William
```

After that, I want group by ShopID. My expected result as below:

```
ShopID | PersonName
--------------------
  1    |    Alex
  2    | John / William
```

I have try refer: [Combine multiple rows into one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422649/combine-multiple-rows-into-one-row). and http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/. But it doesn't what I want.

How do I combine multiple rows into one row in a different table?

Comment: What is the maximum number of persons per shop?

Comment: Have you tried something? What doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `for xml` option to concatenate the results.  The `stuff` function is used to remove the first instance of forward slash, and the `xml.value` function is used to keep `&, <, >` and other special characters from being XML endoded to `&amp; &gt; &lt;`, etc.

There was a bug in my original answer query, here is the edited version:

```
Select s.shopid, 
Stuff (
(
    select ' / '  + p.personName 
    from person p 
    inner join shop s2 on s2.personID = p.personID
    where s2.shopID = s.shopID
    For xml path(''), TYPE --for xml to place everything under node '', which will concatenate the results.
) 
.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') --this is used to convert the XML to nvarchar(max), so that &, <, >, and other special chars do not get XML encoded.
, 1,3,'') --use stuff to replace first 3 characters with empty string.
as PersonName
From shop s
Group by s.shopid 
;
```